# Can you use wild cards in the replace part of Excel's Find & Replace?

Tags: excel

I have a series of formulas that all start the same way but end differently and I want to replace them with a variant of the original formula. Using a wild card, I can find all the functions I want however I cannot figure out how to use the wild card in the replace function.
My search function looks like this right now:
[image]

If I try replacing a formula like this I get Excel's standard "There's a problem with this formula" pop up box--I assume because it reads the `*`s as multiplication signs rather than wild cards.

Is there any way to use wild cards in the replace part of Excel's Find and Replace function?

Alternatively, is there another way I can take a series of different existing formulas and replace them with another formula based on the original formula?

Comment: Edit the first formula in a column, copy the cell, select the whole column (CTRL-SHIFT-Arrow Down) and paste.

Comment: My problem is I have a lot of different sections (~20, it's a mess) so I'm hoping there's a less-brute force solution.

Comment: A simple test will show you that you can. That being said, I don't think you are using the wildcard correctly. Why would there be any in the "Replace with:" field ?

Comment: When I hit replace in the above box, the wildcard in the Replace doesn't seem to work.
The reason I want a wildcard in the replace field is that I have a lot of formulas that begin the way the "Find" formula does, and then vary (different criteria for different tables) but I want to put all of them into an otherwise identical if statement.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I see what you meant to do now. You can't use wildcard in the "Replace with" field. Tell me, was the point to increment the part of your formula that is sheet names?
Because you struggled with apostrophes(') ? If it is the case there's a way around it..

Comment: Unless I misunderstand the question, no, it isn't an issue with incrementing the formula.  Pretty much that formula and it's variants (each with different criteria in the `SUMIFS` statements) use data on another sheet to produce a series of costs in one currency. I want to create a toggle to change the currency on the sheet with all the tables--so inserting the existing `SUMIFS` into a new `IF` statement which has an identical format in every cell; the only difference between the `IF` statements will be the present differences between the existing `SUMIFS` statements. Does that clarify things?